# Why was 36 Edward III c. 1 in French while 25 Edward I c. 1 was in Latin?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-history

These laws were only passed about 65 years apart. Was there a shift from Latin into French during this period?

Comment: Perhaps better asked on [Stack Exchange English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). Of possible interest is [The Role of French in Thirteenth-Century England](https://anglo-norman.net/the-role-of-french-in-thirteenth-century-england/)

Comment: I would disagree. Presumably there were legal reasons for the use of each language

Comment: I don't think you do any research yourself. Please see [Law French – When Law and Language Collide](http://blogs.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/lawbod/2018/05/31/law-french-when-law-and-language-collide/). *During the reign of Edward I the first statute was written in French and Law was professionalised*.

Comment: You wouldn’t; you would rather simply choose a site that seems best fitting for the question and ask on that. In this case I chose law.

Comment: You had this answered already [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/89311/10334)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did French have such a lasting influence on the English legal lexicon?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/89311/why-did-french-have-such-a-lasting-influence-on-the-english-legal-lexicon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Law Bod's Blog, Law French – When Law and Language Collide](http://blogs.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/lawbod/2018/05/31/law-french-when-law-and-language-collide/):

> ... After 1066 French became the language of the elite. During the reign of Edward I the first statute was written in French and Law was professionalised[1](http://blogs.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/lawbod/2018/05/31/law-french-when-law-and-language-collide/). This led to the development of a weird little dialect called law French.

> As you can see from the image below law French is a bizarre mix of French, Latin, Anglo-Saxon and whatever other languages happened to be hanging around. ...
>
> Continental French was originally being used in courts but during the reign of Henry III and Edward I Anglo-French was used to create an entirely new legal vocabulary ‘giving special meanings to ordinary words ...

<sup>Above from the second result returned from a web search for "why was french used for English law". The first result, [a Wikipedia article about law French](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_French), is also informative.</sup>